# Cannot use timestamp in Android Studio(Java), when the button is clicked, Simulator would shout down

Tags: java, android-studio, timestamp

long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();

ts.setText((int) millis);

Now trying to show timestamp when "buttonEqual" is clicked, but suddenly it does not work.

I tried to change long -> int and just put millis in side the setText(), but not appropriate.

```js
 buttonEqual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {



                if (Addition || Subtract || Multiplication || Division || mRemainder) {
                    input2 = Float.parseFloat(edt1.getText() + "");
                }

                if (Addition) {
                    edt1.setText(input1 + "+" + input2);
                    Addition = false;
                    ans.setText(" = " + (input1 + input2) + "");
                    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    ts.setText((int) millis);

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EditText.setText()` expects either a resource id (as int value, specifying a text resource) or a string (with the text to display). Your timestamp is neither.

Assuming that you want to display the timestamp as value, you should write

```
ts.setText(Long.toString(millis));
```